# jQuery - change selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I found some code to copy selected text (for example: [this](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html)) but there is no way to change that text to be available in `clipboard`.

How to change that text in `clipboard`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has no access to the clipboard due to [security policy](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard).

Possibly Flash may help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [ZeroClipBoard library](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) in order to manage clipboard in other browser than IE.

Hope that helps.